# Why is NpgsqlDataReader much slower from V3 onwards?

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am busy upgrading an old system that uses a Postgres database v9 to v14,
I need to update the Npgsql library from its current version 2.2.7 to 4.1.12 on a C# .NetFramework 4.6.1 application.

In my tests, I have noticed that a command that executes a function and reads the response into an array using NpgsqlDataReader takes 10 times longer if I use Npgsql v3 or higher.

The Code looks as follow the **while (dbReader.Read())** loop:
Running Npgsql v2.2.7 takes 10 seconds to run through 20000 rows when connected to the Postgres v9 database.
Running Npgsql v3 or higher takes 140 seconds to run through 20000 rows when connected to the Postgres v9 or v14 database (the db does not make a difference).

```
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;

namespace UpgradeV2.Sample
{
    internal class SampleRequest
    {

        private static string connectionstring = "server=myhostname;port=5432;database=mydatabase;user id=myuser;password=mypassword;enlist=true;pooling=false;minpoolsize=1;maxpoolsize=100;timeout=1024;commandtimeout=3000;";

        public static IEnumerable<DataClass> GetData(long id)
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"i_id", (int)id}             
            };
            using (NpgsqlConnection _npgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                var command = new NpgsqlCommand
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    Connection = _npgsqlConnection,
                    CommandText = "public.function_returning_lots_of_data"
                };

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {                  
                        command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = parameter.Key, Value = parameter.Value });
                }
             
                using (var dbReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {                   
                    var dataList = new Collection<DataClass>();

                    // to complete this while loop with npgsql v2 takes 10 seconds
                    // to complete this while loop with npgsql v3-v6 takes 140 seconds
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {

                        if (dbReader["id"] == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        DataClass item = new DataClass()
                        {
                            id = dbReader.GetFieldValue<int>("id"),
                            //And about 20 other Fields read using GetFieldValue
                        };

                        dataList.Add(item);
                    }
                    return dataList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different newer versions of the Npgsql library and it all results in the same problem from version 3 onwards.
I tried updating the connection string to a higher value for "Read Buffer Size" and it does not have any improvement
I tried using the ExecuteAsync and ReadAsync methods, which have little to no effect.

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/3.0.html "Version 3.0 represents a near-total rewrite of Npgsql. In addition to changing how Npgsql works internally and communicates with PostgreSQL, a conscious effort was made to better align Npgsql with the ADO.NET specs/standard and with SqlClient where that made sense. This means that you cannot expect to drop 3.0 as a replacement to 2.2 and expect things to work - upgrade cautiously and test extensively before deploying anything to production."

Comment: What if you specify `DbType` when creating a `NpgsqlParameter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer Npgsql versions are **very** unlikely to actually be slower than 2.2.7; you haven't posted the complete code, so I'm going to assume that there's some sort of problem with the way you're measuring. For example, it's very possible that the **first** Npgsql operation is slow, since e.g. Npgsql needs to load type information from the database; so if you're just measuring the time for a single request, that's going to be very skewed.

I highly recommend writing up a proper benchmark with BenchmarkDotNet; you just have to write a single function, and that library handles all the actual benchmarking for you (e.g. it runs it in a warmup phase before starting a measurement).

If you can submit a BenchmarkDotNet benchmark that shows 2.2.7 actually performing significantly better than modern versions, I'd definitely want to look at it. I also suggest using recent versions (e.g. 8.0) and not 4.x, which itself is very old by now.

Comment: To Measure my speed I used DateTime to measure the timespan between the start of the loop and until completion just didn't add it to my code example. even without the timespan check the the difference between 10 seconds and 140 seconds is noticeable. I will give BenchmarkDotNet a try and post when I get time.

Comment: How many iterations did you run the benchmark? If just once, that's really meaningless. Did you account for warmup, i.e. perform some iterations first whose timing you disregard? If not, that's once again a totally skewed measurement. This is why BenchmarkDotNet is very recommended when doing benchmarking.

Comment: Regardless, it is *always* highly recommend to provide a *full* code sample when posting a question or issue, and never to omit anything. A fully runnable, minimal code sample is vital for helping others help you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice: 
- I will be sure to post a full code update as soon as I can for now loading it in a data table matches the speed I had before the update).  
- I will get back to this one for discussion when I have time as I am curious In my case it was slower when updated from v2

Comment: I found the main issue causing the slowdown was unrelated to the newer versions of npgsql, its was an extension for the the GetFieldValue method in our code that called the .GetSchemaTable() from the reader twice. I also checked it seems you are a main contributor to the npgsql library , do you mind if I ask you a question? I am working on a legacy system and fixing issues on 100's of functions where the parameter names and types don't match the DB names (usually casing) and types, is there a way to deactivate this validation and let it run regardless like V2 did?

Comment: I don't think there's a way, no. Note that you don't have to use parameter names at all - you can simply invoke functions and use standard positional parameters instead (see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#stored-functions-and-procedures for more info). But of course that still means you need to go over your code unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the most optimal solution but it has significantly increased the speed at which results are read into the array, so I hope this can help someone until a more elegant solution is found.

To do this, I create a data table and read the entire result into the data table using the load method and from there, I create a DataTableReader to take the place of the NpgsqlDataReader.

Using this the dbReader.Read() loop will complete in 5 seconds with 20000 records (in my case that is). The code below will take about 10 seconds to fill the data table and create the adapter.
It's still not as fast as the Npgsql v2.2.7 library but much better than a 140-second load time.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
return dataTable.CreateDataReader();
```

**Please take note:**
This is a solution to my specific problem, I know the original code in the question should be refactored to be optimized for more modern approaches however, this is just one small part of a massive system legacy system that will be eventually retired, where cases like this occur throughout hundreds of classes + files.
So a quick universal fix for the performance issue is my only option at this stage.